# Using XSL include statements with variables

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a group of xsl sub stylesheets which i need to include into a parent stylesheet, all of which are contained in a directory below the parent. I have been using relative paths for the include statements however these now need to be changed full qualified paths.

As these all share the same directory it makes sense to do this with a variable defined in the parent stylesheet eg.

```
<xsl:variable name="module_path" select="C:/stylesheet/modules"/>
```

However when used within the include statement like:

```
<xsl:include href="{$module_path}/substylesheet1.xsl"/>
```

I get the error could not find part of the path "C:/stylesheet/$module_path/substylesheet1.xsl".

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use computed href expression in an `<xsl:include>`. Only literal (i.e. hard-coded) URIs are allowed.

Of course relative URIs are supported, so "hard-coded" does not also mean "absolute".

Comment: +1 Check out things you can't do in xslt http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/nono.html point# 12